# How can I apply a dark mask layer on a QPixmap?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside, qpixmap

I am fairly new to Qt and have been doing a lot of reading and practicing exercises. 
I have searched for this one quite a lot but I could not find any examples.

I have a QPixmap object to which I load a .png image.
I need to create a copy of this QPixmap with a dark mask applied to it.

Basically I want this QPixmap's image to be covered with a layer of solid black of which the opacity is set to 50%.

I know how to set the opacity of a QPixmap's image but how can I add a layer of solid black with opacity on it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `QPainter` and you a semi-transparent `QBrush` to paint that dark layer onto your `QPixmap`.

Assuming `pic` is a `QPixmap` loaded with your image:

```
QPainter p(&pic);
QBrush b(QColor(0,0,0,128)); // adjust color and alpha to taste
p.setBrush(b);
p.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

Effect (before/after):

> [image]    vs   
> [image]

The opaque black border can be removed by setting an semi-transparent pen before painting.
Copy the pixmap before applying the "mask" if you want to preserve the original.